# Declare a global boolean array in drools rule

Tags: drools

I am trying to create a global boolean array in the rule file, and the value for this array is set from the java program. Are primitive arrays supported in drools?

**Rule file**

```
global String topicLevel
global boolean[] rulesList
global java.util.List outList

rule "Test"
when
  $droolsTest : DroolsTest( measurename == "measure1")
then
boolean result1 = rulesList[0] && rulesList[1]  ||  rulesList[2]  &&  rulesList[3]  ;

....
....
```

The above drools file doesn't compile properly. What could be the problem?

Comment: Are you getting any error or unexpected behavior?

Comment: @EstebanAliverti The rules file doesn't compile properly it seems. Aren't primitive arrays supported in drools?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
global java.util.List outList

---

List<Boolean> outList = new ArrayList<>();
kSession.setGlobal("outList", outList)
```